# Explicitly define the possibility of multiple unknown arguments in PHP

Tags: php, arguments, function-declaration

I want to create a function that may require multiple unknown arguments. I am currently not defining the argument list. The function definition looks like this

`public static function SafeJoin()`

and then I use `$arguments_list = func_get_args();` inside the function to get the arguments into the list.

The problem with this approach is that there is no explicit way to know that the function can receive multiple arguments. Are there any approaches to the problem other than using an array as the explicit argument.

Comment: So, you want to create a function that can receive multiple arguments or do you want a method to find out if it can? In case of the latter, why? Shouldn't you know that yourself?

Comment: I guess you know how to handle the multiple arguments like in the example at [func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/de/function.func-get-args.php). So I guess your question is about how to define it or add the correct *PHPdoc*, so your GUI shows the right hints when you hover over the function?

Comment: @rubo77, you are close. I do not exactly want to 'PHPDoc' it. The thingy is called the splat or the scatter operator. See Forien's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is. But was added in PHP version **5.6**.

```
function myFunction(...$params)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($params);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Inside function `$params` is simple array. You can call function with for example: `myFunction(1,'foo',250,$bar);`

[Click! for reference](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)